# Importing a project from Github and .so file issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, .so

I have tried importing a project of Github in Eclipse. Following is the link of that project:
https://github.com/matthill/darwinwallet

But, I am getting the following error when I am trying to run it.

```
10-18 16:51:37.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17728): Process: com.ndu.mobile.darwinwallet, PID: 17728
10-18 16:51:37.100: E/AndroidRuntime(17728): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ndu.mobile.darwinwallet-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative_wallet.so"
```

I don't have any idea about *.so* files and how to create them. If you can provide step by step instruction on how to do that (or provide one for my project) will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native library is missing.
You need to build native library from source in jni folder. Details of building native library can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Comment: I have already built NDK. can you please tell me step by step process to compile the JNI folder/source to .so file .

Comment: It depends on project, normally you just have run ndk_build command from your jni folder.